# New google account has no albumid in picasa web albums data API

Tags: google-api, picasa, google-data-api

Hi i try to download photos from google photo to my backend with picasa web albums data API.

In order to download photos with this api, i have to know the **albumID**.

For testing propose i made a brand new gmail account, and upload photos to the google photo of this new account and make photo albums.

Based on the documentation 
https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol

I send this request with the new account **userID**:
GET https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/userID

The problem is that there is no **albumID** at all.

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/' xmlns:gphoto='http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007'>
      <id>https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/<userID></id>
      <updated>1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</updated>
      <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#user'/>
      <title type='text'><userID></title>
      <subtitle type='text'/>
      <icon>https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-31_aw60BK4Y/AAAAAAAAAAA/AAAAAAAAAAA/6nUp0GOreV8/s64-c/<userID>.jpg</icon>
      <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/<userID>'/>
      <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/<userID>'/>
      <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#slideshow' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' href='https://photos.gstatic.com/media/slideshow.swf?host=picasaweb.google.com&amp;RGB=0x000000&amp;feed=https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/<userID>?alt%3Drss'/>
      <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/<userID>?start-index=1&amp;max-results=1000'/>
      <author>
          <name><userID></name>
          <uri>https://picasaweb.google.com/<userID></uri>
      </author>
      <generator version='1.00' uri='http://picasaweb.google.com/'>Picasaweb</generator>
      <openSearch:totalResults>0</openSearch:totalResults>
      <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
      <openSearch:itemsPerPage>1000</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
      <gphoto:user><userID></gphoto:user>
      <gphoto:nickname><userID></gphoto:nickname>
      <gphoto:thumbnail>https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-31_aw60BK4Y/AAAAAAAAAAA/AAAAAAAAAAA/6nUp0GOreV8/s64-c/<userID>.jpg</gphoto:thumbnail>
  </feed>
```

Where did i missed?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I corrected the question.